# Why am I seeing net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED errors after upgrading to Cordova Android 8?

Tags: android, cordova

After upgrading to [Cordova Android 8.0](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/02/16/cordova-android-release-8.0.0.html), I am seeing `net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED` errors when trying to connect to `http://` targets.

Why is that and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 289, accepted):

The default API level in the Cordova Android platform has been upgraded. On an Android 9 device, clear text communication is now [disabled by default](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted).

To allow clear text communication again, set the `android:usesCleartextTraffic` on your `application` tag to `true`:

```xml
<platform name="android">
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
      <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
  </edit-config>
</platform>
```

As noted in the comments, if you have not defined the `android` XML namespace previously, you will receive an `error: unbound prefix` during build. This indicates that you need to add it to your `widget` tag in the same `config.xml`, like so:

```xml
<widget id="you-app-id" version="1.2.3"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Comment: I encountered an error (`error: unbound prefix.`) when trying to build my Cordova application. The solution was to add in my `config.xml` file, in the my root `<widget>` element the attribute `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`

Comment: @Der Hochstapler Can you add apiagets comment to your answer?

Comment: @MichaelB Everyone can edit answers and is welcome to do so. But, sure, I'll do it.

Comment: @SteevJames Did you rebuild your Cordova project so that the changes are actually persisted into the Android project structure? Have you verified that the changes have been made to the `AndroidManifest.xml` in your Android project?

Comment: this work but in my case i have to remove platform android and then after it work.

Comment: In short, I added this line to my manifest under `<application>` and it fixed my issue:
`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Comment: I add in  `edit-config` this:
`<domain includeSubdomains="true">api.example.com(to be adjusted)</domain>` and it's work for me.        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Comment: this is all good but which files am I supposed to add this to?

Comment: manually add "android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml is the only fix for me on cordova@9.0.0. a js script for auto replace it https://gist.github.com/JaosnHsieh/532d3b790090e1099415f1c11f2a7b62

Comment: That was not enough in my case. I also had to specify the host I needed to communicate with as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57108997/3095695

Comment: You saved me! I was desperate to connect to a websocket server without ssl :^P

Answer (score 54):

There are two things to correct in config.xml
So the right answer should be adding the xmls:android:

```
<widget id="com.my.awesomeapp" version="1.0.0" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

plus editing the config to allow:

```
<platform name="android">
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
      <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
  </edit-config>
</platform>
```

If step 1 is avoided error: unbound prefix. will appear

Comment: results syntax error in config.xml file

Answer (score 49):

Cleartext here represents unencrypted information. Since Android 9, it is recommended that apps should call HTTPS APIs to make sure there is no eves dropping.

However, if we still need to call HTTP APIs, we can do following:

**Platform: Ionic 4**

Create a file named: **network_security_config.xml** under **project-root/resources/android/xml**

Add following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
   <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
     <domain>ip-or-domain-name</domain>
   </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Now in **project-root/config.xml**, update following lines:

```
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
    </edit-config>
    ... other statements...
```

It should work now.

Comment: Thanks bro, It worked for me for Ionic 4. I specified domain name <domain>example.com</domain> and it worked. Also got help from this "https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config"

Comment: Why is the "<edit-config.." OVERWRITTEN each time i run the app ?

Comment: This works but I need to add this line in ```config.xml``` before the ```edit-config``` tag: ```<resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />```. Thanks!

Comment: @ZakiMohammed please share your code i am also facing a same problem help!

Comment: @jose please have a look to my answer

Answer (score 39):

To solve the problem there's other option. 
in file resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml. insert:

```
<network-security-config>
   <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <trust-anchors>
           <certificates src="system" />
       </trust-anchors>
   </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain>localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.7.213:8733</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Im my case I´m using IP address then base-config is necessary, but if you have a domain. just add the domain.

Comment: While all the accepted solution was also required, this answer was key for the problem I was facing.

Comment: Thank you! I'm also using an IP instead of a domain name and your answer fit perfectly!

Answer (score 35):

I ran into this problem myself today, and found a really nifty plugin that will save you the hassle of trying to manually allow cleartext traffic in Android 9+ for your Apache Cordova application. Simply install cordova-plugin-cleartext, and the plugin should take care of all the behind the scenes Android stuff for you.

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-cleartext
$ cordova prepare
$ cordova run android
```

Comment: For others looking for the answer. I kept getting hit by other errors when applying the config fixes, but this worked straight away. Thanks Topher

Comment: Works for me. Thx!

Comment: For those using, Ionic don't forget 
"ionic cordova prepare"

Answer (score 19):

After a few days of struggle, this works for me, and I hope this also works for you.

add this to your **CONFIG.XML**, top of your code.

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

and this, under the platform android.

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" 
   mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
     <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
 </edit-config>
 <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" 
 target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
```

add the follow code to this file **"resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml"**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">YOUR DOMAIN HERE/IP</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please answer this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59116787/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted

Comment: thanks for you solution, It's the only one that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, its the only solution one that worked for me to.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me.  Specifically it seemed the `trust-anchors` tags was the final component to get all the other stuff working.

Comment: If you are using phonegab build then keep network_security_config on root folder and give path as resource-file src="network_security_config.xml"

Comment: For those using, Ionic don't forget 
"ionic cordova prepare"

Answer (score 15):

Adding the following attribute within the opening < widget > tag worked for me. Simple and live reloads correctly on a Android 9 emulator.  **xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"**

```
<widget id="com.my.awesomeapp" version="1.0.0" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Comment: I did not realize when I saw this answer, but this is _in addition to_ the `edit-config` code from the accepted answer (fixes the `unbound prefix` error)

Comment: @RishiG now it is an answer that explains the full right answer

Comment: @zardilior Yes, congrats on him for hijacking the answer on an edit... lol

Answer (score 11):

Im using IONIC 5.4.13, cordova 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

I might be repeating information but for me problem started appearing after adding some plugin (not sure yet).
I tried all above combinations, but nothing worked.
It only started working after adding:

```
   <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <trust-anchors>
           <certificates src="system" />
       </trust-anchors>
   </base-config>
```

to file in project at

> resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml

so my network_security_config.xml file now looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
   <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <trust-anchors>
           <certificates src="system" />
       </trust-anchors>
   </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.1.25.10</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: How is this different from the existing Ionic solution(s)?

Comment: situation is different. remember people come here from google search. there might be different situation and settings they land in this issue. in my case my project was working fine and it just started giving this error even i have not done any platform update or device update.

Comment: Because people end up here from a Google search, it should be in everyone's interested to present a useful list of solutions and not many duplicates that only make minor adjustments. Instead, you should try to improve an existing answer.

Comment: Sorry @Det Hochstapler, I do agree with you at some extent. I don't want to stretch this too much. But as per my opinion, adding to original answer will unnecessarily make it complex. As I said there is nothing much in answer but it matters in which situations I'm getting error. I'm still finding out more about it and I'll definitely add to my answer about it.

Comment: Thanks champ, this worked for me :) -- it's nice to have the confirmation of version updates for working solutions, as time goes by and old solutions no longer work, especially in a volatile ever-changing framework.

Comment: thanks mate, wanted to say that for me this was the only working solution

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. I tried many other suggestions but was not working.

Comment: Welcome, @MasterJedi ... In the latest ionic, I guess this is built-in.

Comment: I still have one issue, how to make IP/domain in includeSubdomains part dynamic or wildcard. As I'm dealing with IoT devices, and IPs of every customer device is not predictable. So how to resolve this for an app that needs to be distributed over PlayStore. Now I have switched to the latest ionic and I still have this issue. I know I can resolve it by hardcoding IP, but I don't want it like that.

Answer (score 10):

After reading the whole discussion looking for a way to authorize communication to all IP addresses as in my case the IP address to where the request will be sent is defined by the user in an input text and can not be defined in the configuration file. Here is how I resolved the issue

here are the configuration

**config.xml**

```
<platform name="android">
...
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
...
</platform>
```

**resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

The most important piece of code is `<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />` in `<network-security-config>` instead of `domain-config`

Comment: setting the **base-config** element resolved the issue, thanks a ton! 

Answer (score 7):

you should add

```
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
```

to

> resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml

like this

```
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>

<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
</domain-config> </network-security-config>
```

Comment: Why is this important?

Answer (score 7):

Just add this line to platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" **android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"**>
```

Answer (score 6):

Following is the solution which worked for me. The files which I updated are as follows:

1. config.xml (Full Path: /config.xml)
2. network_security_config.xml (Full Path: /resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml)

Changes in the corresponding files are as follows:

**1. config.xml**

I have added `<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />` tag within `<edit-config>` tag in the config.xml file

```
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
    </edit-config>
    ...
<platform name="android">
```

**2. network_security_config.xml**

In this file I have added 2 `<domain>` tag within `<domain-config>` tag, the main domain and a sub domain as per my project requirement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">mywebsite.in</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">api.mywebsite.in</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Thanks @Ashutosh for the providing the help.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Following solution worked for me-

goto `resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml`
Change it to-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">api.example.com(to be adjusted)</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 2):

Old ionic cli (4.2) was causing issue in my case, update to 5 solve the problem

Comment: Thank you.  This was the solution for me.  I had a separate build process running on App Center that was installing ionic to run ionic cli commands.  They have deprecated "ionic" in favor of "@ionic/cli".

Answer (score 2):

I am running Ionic 5 with Vue and Capacitor 3 and was getting this error using the [InAppBrowser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser) for a website that doesn't support https. For Capacitor apps, `config.xml` isn't used and `AndroidManifest.xml` is edited directly.

First, create the Network Security Config file here `YOUR_IONIC_APP_ROOT\android\app\main\res\xml\network_security_config.xml`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
   <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain>www.example.com</domain>
   </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Then edit `YOUR_IONIC_APP_ROOT\android\app\main\AndroidManifest.xml` adding `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to `application`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.ionic.starter">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"

        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!-- ... -->
    </application>
    <!-- ... -->
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Der Hochstapler thanks for the solution.
but in **IONIC 4** some customization in project **config.xml** work for me

Add a line in Widget tag

```
<widget id="com.my.awesomeapp" version="1.0.0" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

after this, in the Platform tag for android customize some lines check below
add **usesCleartextTraffic=true** after **networkSecurityConfig** and **resource-file** tags

```
 <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
    </platform>
```

Comment: How is this different from the existing Ionic solution(s)?

Comment: i was added "android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" with "android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" inside single <edit-config> tag so that was not working for me and when i added new <edit-config> tag for "android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"" and also paste after "android:networkSecurityConfig" <edit-config> tag then it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

We are using the [`cordova-custom-config`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) plugin to manage our Android configuration.  In this case the solution was to add a new [`custom-preference`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config#android-preferences) to our `config.xml`:

```
    <platform name="android">

        <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />

        <!-- ... other settings ... -->

        <!-- Allow http connections (by default Android only allows https) -->
        <!-- See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752716/ -->
        <custom-preference
            name="android-manifest/application/@android:usesCleartextTraffic"
            value="true" />

    </platform>
```

Does anybody know how to do this only for development builds?  I would be happy for release builds to leave this setting `false`.

(I see the iOS configuration offers `buildType="debug"` for that, but I'm not sure if this applies to Android configuration.)

Answer (score 0):

In an Ionic 4 capacitor project, when I packaged and deployed to android phone for testing I got this error. Resolved by re-installing capacitor and updating android platform.

```
npm run build --prod --release
npx cap copy
npm install --save @capacitor/core @capacitor/cli
npx cap init
npx cap update android
npx cap open android
```

Answer (score 0):

If You have Legacy Cordova framework having issues with NPM and Cordova command. I would suggest the below option.

**Create file android/res/xml/network_security_config.xml -**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">Your URL(ex: 127.0.0.1)</domain>
    </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml -**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest ...>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <application
            ...
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
            ...>
            ...
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: How is this different from the existing Ionic solution(s)?

Comment: Some legacy projects doesn't follow NPM and Cordova commands which has to be manually updated.

Comment: why <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" /> and not false? you would like to only allow your custom domain and block others, that's what the domain-config element is for

Answer (score 0):

I put
manifest -- aplication -- android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

and build.gradle - defaut config --  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

works for me

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/err-cleartext-not-permitted-in-debug-app-on-android/164101/20) works with ionic 7:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application  
android:icon="@mipmap/icon" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
... 
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" // add this line
>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of answers/suggestions on this now (kind of too many) but just sharing what worked for me to (finally) get rid of the "ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED" issue on Android (as of 11/2023):

```
    <!-- add this to in the main widget node of your Cordova config.xml -->
    <preference name="android-usesCleartextTraffic" value="true" />
```

This will add the `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the `<application>` node of your AndroidManifest.xml file when you `$ cordova build android`.