# I get an err_cleartext_not_permitted for http

Tags: webview, flutter

I get `ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED` for Android and blank page for iOS when I use `http://` URLs.

`https://` URLs seem to work.

The very same `http://` URLs work fine in Chrome.

I recall I had the same problem in native Android as well some year ago.
Is it possible to tell webview "please use `http://`. I will take the risk"?

I'm using webview_flutter: ^0.3.2+1

Comment: from a similar answer by @nimit check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55592392/how-to-fix-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-in-flutter <application
....
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
....>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752716/why-am-i-seeing-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-errors-after-upgrading-to-cordo/56262624#56262624

Answer (score 8):

1) For Android check *./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<manifest ....
    ....
    **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />**
    <application
        **android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"**
    </application>
    ...
</manifest>
```

2) For ios you need to modify the info.plist *./ios/Runner/info.plist*

Add the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

3) After that do *flutter clean* for your project.

Answer (score -2):

I get the answer
Ex:
Url =  http//:[www.google.com/](http://www.google.com/)
change Url

```
        Url = http//:www.google.com
```

This is working fine

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34689597)