# How to fix 'net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED' in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have implemented webView in flutter but it is not opening my php website which is on server what I'm doing wrong.

I am new to flutter and tried webview to integrate my website webpage in my application but no luck.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return WebviewScaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(iconTheme:IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),title: Text("Intake Form",style:new TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),backgroundColor:Colors.indigoAccent,automaticallyImplyLeading: false),
     url: url,
      //url: "http://xxxxxxxx/",
       withJavascript: true,
       supportMultipleWindows: true,
      withLocalStorage: true,
      allowFileURLs: true,
      enableAppScheme: true,
      appCacheEnabled: true,
      hidden: false,
      scrollBar: true,
      geolocationEnabled: false,
      clearCookies: true,
       // usesCleartextTraffic="true"



    );
  }
```

I expect the output as running webview but error is thrown.

Answer (score 140):

In main directory of your Flutter project you have three main folders:

```
- lib         =  your Dart code
- ios         =  generated structure for iOS platform
- android     =  generated structure for Android platform
```

We are interested in `android` directory.
When you open it, you will see "typical Android app structure".

So you have to do 2 things:

## 1) Add new file in `res`

Go to directory:

```
my_flutter_project/android/app/src/main/res/
```

Create `xml` directory (in `res`!)

And inside `xml` add new file with name: `network_security_config.xml` and content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

`network_security_config.xml` should be located in path:

```
my_flutter_project/android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml
```

[image: network_security_config]

> Here you can find more information about this file:
>
> https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

## 2) Modify AndroidManifest.xml

Go to:

```
flutter_project/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

[image]

`AndroidManifest.xml` is XML file, with structure:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <activity>
            ...
        </activity>
        <meta-data >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

So for `<application>` PROPERTIES you have to add 1 line:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

[image]

### Remember that you have to **add it as property** (inside `application` opening tag):

```
<application

    SOMEWHERE HERE IS OK

>
```

Not as a tag:

```
<application>           <--- opening tag

    HERE IS WRONG!!!!

<application/>          <--- closing tag
```

Comment: What a wonderful answer with every step explained with complete clarity!

Comment: I can't understand why topic starter hasn't accepted this answer. It really works! Thanks, and take my upvote

Comment: The answer is correct here is my perception according to the question is that when a developer implement an site with http:// then this security file is needed else if you just change the url with https:// you will not get any error in the web view

Comment: it is wonderful example and explained simple and very easy working method, thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to restart the app for the changes to take effect

Comment: does anyone know how to enable this in **development** only?

Comment: @transang would you like to use `productFlavors` (e.g. "test", "internal", "paid", "free" etc.) or `buildTypes` ("debug" / "release")?

Comment: in my case, I want the `buildTypes`. In local dev, I want to connect to the LAN host that is HTTP, while in production build, it is https

Comment: this is most elaborate answer ever!!! thanks

Comment: I wanna use zoom and trading view on flutter, trading view need usesCleartextTraffic to true and plugin zoom is false, can this method work? @Boken

Answer (score 92):

set usesCleartextTraffic property to true in your AndroidManifest file, like below.

```
<application
....
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
....>
```

Comment: Even with this option, it doesn't work  :/ I had to run `flutter clean` and then rerun the project again

Comment: @lonelLupu Possible no need for cleaning. Seems that stop the whole app and *rebuild* it is enough. The reason is that, the AndroidManifest does not reload with Flutter's hot reload/restart.

Comment: Simple and very easy working method.

Comment: I personally think setting this to true goes against Android best practices related network security; https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element . From Android 8 this property is false by default.

Answer (score 28):

**Android:**

In flutter_project/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

***Add***

```
<application
....
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
....>
```

**IOS:**

In flutter_project/ios/Runner/info.plist

***Add***

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Run `flutter clean`.Then, run the app.

Answer (score 4):

For ios modify info.plist `./ios/Runner/info.plist`

Add the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

and run `flutter clean` before spinning up the app again

Answer (score 1):

- make network_security_config.xml file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <network-security-config>
            <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
                <trust-anchors>
                    <certificates src="system" />
                </trust-anchors>
            </base-config>
        </network-security-config>
```

[image]

- add this two line in Manifest file in  Application tag.

Comment: Where exactly this file needs to be placed?

Comment: in res folder make xml folder and then put this .xml file.

Comment: I am working in flutter, so there is no res folder in there.

Comment: According to docs: This flag is ignored on Android 7.0 (API level 24) and above if an Android Network Security Config is present.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented webView in Flutter, Try `flutter_inappwebview`:
flutter_inappwebview: ^6.0.0
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview

**Getting Started:**
https://inappwebview.dev/docs/intro

**Requirements:**

Dart sdk: ">=2.17.0 <4.0.0" Flutter: ">=3.0.0" Android: minSdkVersion >= 19, compileSdk >= 34, AGP version >= 7.3.0 (use Android Studio - Android Gradle plugin Upgrade Assistant for help), support for androidx (see AndroidX Migration to migrate an existing app) iOS 9.0+: --ios-language swift, Xcode version >= 14.3 MacOS 10.11+: Xcode version >= 14.3