# Error net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED in webview_flutter, How to solve this?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, webview-flutter

I'm encountering this net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED in [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) in android 10, [Screenshot of Error in Android version 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tIAb.png), but this error is not coming in Android version 8 or below.

I tried adding

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

[I referred to this to solve this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55592392/how-to-fix-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-in-flutter) but still didn't worked.
Did I missed anything?