# Did not find frame

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-webview

I get the following error when using InAppWebview and switching between pages,
works in one emulator, not in another

```
 E/FrameEvents( 5237): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
```

Comment: it works on android 6 it doesn't work on android 11 and 12

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55592392/how-to-fix-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-in-flutter , it worked

Comment: what does this have to do with VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

```
 E/FrameEvents( 5237): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
```

Upgrade Your version: flutter_inappwebview: ^6.0.0
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview

**Migration guide, minimum required section:** https://inappwebview.dev/docs/migration-guide