# FrameEvents(31583): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

when I switch to some pages in my application that I set up with InAppwebView, I get this error ( updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame ) the same project works without any problem on the device with android version 6, but on devices with android version 11 12 I get this error. Can you help, thanks in advance

```
       InAppWebView(
                    onWebViewCreated: ((_controller) {
                      controller = _controller;
                    }),

                    initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                        url: Uri.parse('')),
                  
                    initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(

                        crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                          javaScriptEnabled: true,
                          mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
                          supportZoom: false,

                        ),

                        android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(

                          mixedContentMode: AndroidMixedContentMode

                              .MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW,
                        )),

                    onProgressChanged:

                        (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {

                      setState(() {

                        this.progress = progress / 100;

                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55592392/how-to-fix-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-in-flutter , it worked

Comment: Hi Yusuf, could you please explain why that post can resolve this issue? I have the same problem now and I don't know how to fix it. It causes my Flutter app crash on some devices.

Answer (score 1):

I already did the solutions provided here (*"How to fix 'net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED' in flutter*") to let the app show also http content and not https.
It worked for that issue but not for this one.

Any further suggestions?

UPDATE:
I SOLVED IT: **the solutions provided are right but need another passage:**

Inside:

```
controller = WebViewController()
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('YOUR URL'),
      );
```

you have to insert a property to allow the use of javascript:

```
controller = WebViewController()
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
  ..loadRequest(
    Uri.parse('YOUR URL'),
  );
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer]. Concentrate on providing a solution, the history is not important. Consider taking the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Just to restate Yusuf Barulay's comment above - the correct answer to this problem is found in :

[How to fix 'net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED' in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55592392/how-to-fix-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-in-flutter)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35723845)

Answer (score -1):

If your webview application works in old Android versions but does not work in new Android versions, here is what you need to do.

add this code to android manifest file

```
<application...android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Then do flutter clean and run the application again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It doesn't work.