# How to enable http sites to open in webview_flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio, flutterwebviewplugin

I need to open http sites in a webview in my flutter app but it's not working in adnroid. For IOS, I added keys in info.plist files but I can't find a solution for android. Is there any way to allow  to open sites that are not secured?

I am using the package [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

I tried to add the following xml file to allow unsecure sites and providing it's path to AndroidManifest file but it didn't work.

```
android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <!-- You can add trusted certificates here if needed -->
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

This is my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.webview_demo">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="webview_demo"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:exported="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
            android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

My webview code:

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;

  const WebviewScreen({Key? key, required this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WebviewScreen> createState() => _WebviewScreenState();
}

class _WebviewScreenState extends State<WebviewScreen> {
  WebViewController? webViewController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadWebView();
  }

  loadWebView() {
    webViewController = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(Colors.white)
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            log('Page started loading: $url');
          },
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            log('WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)');
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            log('Page finished loading: $url');
          },
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
            log('Webview resource error $error');
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.contains("http:/")) {
              log("first redirection ${request.url}");
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse(widget.url),
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          return true;
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: const BackButton(),
            title: const Text('Webview'),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          body: SafeArea(
            bottom: false,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: WebViewWidget(
                    controller: webViewController!,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Android**

Add a piece of code in label `application` on `AndroidManifst.xml` file

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Add a file named `network_security_config.xml` in `res/xml` directory, The content of the file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

**iOS**

Add a piece of code in label `dict` on `Info.plist` file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict>  
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
</dict>
```

Comment: I am getting the following error in android: 

[WARNING:navigation_controller_impl.cc(276)] Refusing to load for invalid virtual URL: http://***************/

Comment: i have updated my manifest file. Can you please check if I am making a mistake?

Comment: Yes, it seems correct.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably the best / easiest way to create an **WebView** with Flutter.

import the package [**webview_flutter**](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) to your project

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
```

Create a class for the webview:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String websiteURL;
  WebViewContainer({super.key, required this.websiteURL});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _WebViewContainerState();
}

class _WebViewContainerState extends State<WebViewContainer> {
  final controller = WebViewController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(widget.websiteURL));

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("My Web View")),
      body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
    );
  }
}
```

Then call it whenever you want from your code

```
 Navigator.push(context,
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
         WebViewContainer(
            websiteURL:"https://stackoverflow.com")
 ));
```

Don't forget to set `minSdkVersion` in your `android/app/build.gradle` if your version was previously was under 19.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
    }
}
```

After all these is configured, you should open any **HTTPS** website.
However, for **HTTP** sites there are some extra steps.
You can read about them in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60192032/4605422).

Comment: yes this is the plugin I am using, but it won't load sites that are not secured in android.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you were having a specific issue with **HTTP** and not all web views.
I've added a link that should help you.