# Access a page and press a button with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, playback

I need to make a button access a website with flutter and press the button, can anyone give me a path on how to do this?

my onTap looks like this

```
onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          isPlaying = !isPlaying;
        });
      },
```

the website I want to access

https://radio.jmvstream.com/page/OWxx

When the user clicks on the button, it will redirect them to tap on the application

I tried to use the audioplayer plugin to make it play but either I used it wrong or it doesn't work with this type of page

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Flutter or Dart to call directly buttons on a Website.

What you can do, is [create a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77037067/4605422) to load a valid Website URL, and side-load your custom Javascript, which modifies the default behavior of the page.

In your case, it should activate the play event by pressing the button of the radio player, (button onClick, or button pressed).

**The alternative method:**

Since you have the website source, and you know exactly what's the [link of the stream](https://alerrradioon.jmvstream.com/stream), you can create your own view, loading a widget that can play the same audio resource, without loading the full site.

This will require you to have an **audio player-manager**, that supports audio streaming, you must have a valid stream URL and must create all the necessary **controllers** for **loading the stream**, **play**, **stop**, **seek**, etc...