# net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED error on Ionic Android live reload

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

When I run `ionic cordova run android --livereload` I get this error:

net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED (http://192.168.0.5:8100/)

[image: net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED error]

I'm targeting Android SDK 28. I understand that Android does not allow plain HTTP connections anymore.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752716/why-am-i-seeing-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-errors-after-upgrading-to-cordo/56262624#56262624

Comment: use https that all

Answer (score 2):

Add this attribute to `<widget>` tag in your config.xml:

```
<widget ... xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Add this code to your config.xml:

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
  <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
</edit-config>
```

Don't forget to revert these changes when you build release APK file.

Comment: try to use https://