# Release version not working in android 9 How to Solve This?

Tags: android, cordova

I have created android app using Cordova 8.1.0 version and it was successfully uploaded to the Playstore. this is working without any issue in bellow android 9. in android 9 this app is not working.

Then i have installed the debug-apk. it was working as i expected. but relase-apk is not working. how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: in release mode pro-guard affects your app .but in debug mode doesn't.it might be the problem

Comment: Then what should i want to do? Because i am not expert in android?

Comment: what you mean about not working? is not it installed? or crashes ?

Comment: It's installed and opened witout crash. Login screen is openned. But i cant login. I used api for authentication. And user id save in localstorage. Additiinally i used onesignal.

Comment: put toast message when login screen comes up and see where unwanted result pop out. in release mode.

Comment: Sure thaks youbfor. The advice

Comment: did you run and check your logcat for errors?

Comment: #josep no i din't, but debug apk working as i expected without any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Updated Config.xml Like this and solve the problem. the Error Was  ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED

[More details Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752716/why-am-i-seeing-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-errors-after-upgrading-to-cordo)

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>   
     <widget android-versionCode="3001013" defaultlocale="en-US" id="com.siot.employeetraking" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps">
```

do the Bellow change

```
 <platform name="android"> 
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
  </platform>
```