# Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug' Ionic 3

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I let my Ionic 3 application and went back to it several months later, now when I try to build I get this error :

```
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't read [MY_PATH\platforms\android\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar] (Can't process class [module-info.class] (Unsupported class version number [53.0] (maximum 52.0, Java 1.8)))
```

I don't know how to fix it nor what cause this issue, could somebody help me please ?

In my build.gradle I already enabled multidex

```
defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")
        multiDexEnabled true 

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201204/discussion-on-question-by-amanite-laurine-execution-failed-for-task-transformc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very good solution but was the only one I found, reinstall platform android

```
ionic cordova platform rm android

ionic cordova platform add android
```

After that I got the error "net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED" I found the solution here :
[Why am I seeing net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED errors after upgrading to Cordova Android 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752716/why-am-i-seeing-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-errors-after-upgrading-to-cordo)