# Cordova app is not sending request to my localhost server on emulator

Tags: cordova

Cordova app is not sending a request to my localhost server on the emulator but when I type http://192.168.201.27:8080/my_portal/index.jsp on the chrome of emulator it successfully opens the home page of my portal

Comment: try posting the console error, my first guess it is a CORS problem

Comment: app.js:1 GET http://192.168.201.27:8080/my_portal/mobile/MobileAuthenticateUserMDEAppV7?SessionID=2340 net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED

Comment: please refer to the following  Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752716/why-am-i-seeing-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-errors-after-upgrading-to-cordo