# Cordova emulate Android leads to Application Error There was a network error. (http://localhost:8100/)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I know that a similar question was raised under [Why am I seeing net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED errors after upgrading to Cordova Android 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752716/why-am-i-seeing-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-errors-after-upgrading-to-cordo) but unfortunately non of the answers fixed my problem.

[image]

- Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.8.4
- @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.13
- Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)
- Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0, browser 6.0.0
- Android Studio 2020.3.1

After deleting the *platforms* folder of my ionic project, I wanted to emulate my project again by running:

`sudo ./Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_28`

`cordova prepare android`

`ionic cordova emulate android -l`

And all of a sudden I always get the error message that there is a network problem. That has never happened before to me, so I tried to add the configs from the link above. Here is my `resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and part of my `config.xml` (and I tried all versions from the link above!):

```
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
```

I installed new virtual device using Android Studio, but same error.

Comment: Use IP instead of localhost

At capacitor.config.json add I as 

 "server": {
    "url": "http://192.168.xxx",
    "cleartext": true,
    "allowNavigation": [
      "localhost",
      "http://192.168.xxx"
    ]
  }

Answer (score 0):

Check your *config.xml* file and ensure this content source is set like this:

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

Anything else should be removed and revert back to the above.